# How to convert IEnumerable collection into single object using MVC .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My problem is, I am working on ASP .NET MVC Ajax project. In which I am passing collection to the view and iterate this collection using foreach loop, then I want to add new record using `@Ajax.ActionLink()` on the same view, the form will be in the form of dialog box using jQuery UI. But I don't know how to do that because the model object in the form of `IEnumerable` and I am unable to pass model attributes to `@Html.EditorFor()` method, the error is:

> CS1061: 'IEnumerable<Country>' does not contain a definition for 'CountryName' and no extension method 'CountryName' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Country>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

View.cshtml code

```
@model IEnumerable<UBSAjax.Models.Country>
....
<style>
    .deleteButton {
        display:none !important;
    }
</style>
<h2>Counties</h2>
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CountryName)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CountryCode)</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CountryName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CountryCode)</td>
                <td class="deleteButton">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CountryId }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CountryId }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CountryId })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<!--Ajax Assets-->
@{
    AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions();
    options.InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter;
    options.HttpMethod = "GET";
    //options.LoadingElementId = "imgloader";
    //options.LoadingElementDuration = 1000;
    options.Confirm = "Do you want to get form ?????";
    options.OnFailure = "failureFunc";
    options.OnSuccess = "successFunc";
    //options.OnBegin = "beginFunc";
    //options.OnComplete = "completeFunc";
    options.UpdateTargetId = "CountryContentId";
}

<div id="dialog" title="Login Form">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Country", options))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CountryName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Country Name" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CountryCode, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Country Code" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Country" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

`@model IEnumerable<UBSAjax.Models.Country>` is a collection but i want to create form in the same view but above error is occurring.

Comment: Code samples are good way to start here.

Comment: Show the code generating this error. Edit your question and add that code.

Comment: @Janis I have added my code please help

Comment: @user3185569  I have added my code please help

Comment: Use a view model with properties for your new `Country` and a property for the collection. Or use `@Html.Action()` to call a server method that returns a partial view of the form for a new `Country`

Answer (score 0):

Use a view model instead, create one that holds both collection of countries and a single new country data, from there separate the view into display and editor templates respectively

Comment: I just want to cast the collection i.e var obj = (List<Country>), just like that because I am returning collection to the view and in the view i want to convert it into single object

Comment: how to create view model, that will  hold both collection of countries and a single new country data, please show me any example thanks

Comment: Its unconvenient to type the code, basically a viewmodel is just a poco class like your model except you dont add its dbset in the context, make one named countryvm or what you like and make it holds property of IEnumerable<Country> countries and another one that hold a single country data, name it as NewCountry or what, from here change your current view's model with the new vm you made, move the entire table into a display template for country list( google on how to create custom editor and display template) and the form using editor for. Lastly update your controller to use the vm instead